# Reading Xon-Xoff Standard Protocol

Tags: vb.net, printing, serial-port, flow-control

I'm trying to read the state of a old printer connected by RS232. In the manual of the printer I found the settings of the port: Baud 9600, 8 bit, 1 stop bit, No Parity, Flux Control Hardware. The printer accepts a text message and I send is something like: `<MESSAGE>` and for one label works fine.

The problem is the multiprint. If I make a for cycle for print multi messages, I should wait the machine is ready for next print. Still in the manual, I find that the printer uses the Xon-Xoff protocol. Now my cycle  should wait for the char (DC1, 11 hex, 17 dec.) XOn for sending the next one message. I haven't find anything about how to read this value from the serial port. Any suggestions?

I have tried this code only for try to understand how I have to set the parameters, but I have one exception when I try to Open the serialport:

```
        Dim ports As String() = SerialPort.GetPortNames()
        Dim port As String
        For Each port In ports
            If port = "COM1" Then
                '  serialport1.BaudRate = 9600
                '  serialport1.DataBits = 8
                '  serialport1.Parity = Parity.None
                '  serialport1.StopBits = StopBits.One
                '  serialport1.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff
                MessageBox.Show(port)
                If SerialPort1.IsOpen = False Then SerialPort1.Open()
                AddHandler SerialPort1.DataReceived, AddressOf DataReceivedHandler
            End If
        Next port
```

Comment: Set the serial port's Handshake property to Handshake.None, DtrEnable to True, RtsEnable to True.  Use the Read() method to receive data from the printer.

Comment: Are you having trouble doing a lot of printing at one time?  Have you tried setting the handshake of the serialport to xonxoff before you open it?

Comment: "*I found the settings of the port:  ... Flux Control Hardware*" -- Huh?? Do you mean 'Flow control is performed by Hardware?  If you configure the serial driver (in the OS) for the proper handshake or flow-control, then the userspace application can let the OS perform that task, and your program will be unaware of any handshake or flow-control (as long as you use blocking I/O). If you use "Hardware Flow-control", then do not also use XON/XOFF (aka software flow-control). For HW flow-control, you will need the proper cable that carries the additional RTS & CTS signals.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Yes, in practice I have to set the port parameters from the OS, but I also need to be able to read the port status. The port on which the printer is connected is COM1. But I don't have the Handshake from the OS parameters.

Comment: Vote to close because you're asking an XY question, and you ignore responding to questions. You think you need to read "*port status*" in order to continue printing? You haven't explained the problem at all, and only ask how to do something nonsensical.  The typical printer configured for XON/XOFF flow-control will send an XOFF (to its host) when its buffer is full, and an XON when buffer space is available, not when it is ready for the next label. Are you neglecting to send some sort of `Form Feed` or `Vertical Tab` control char to advance to the next label?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how serial ports work with this protocol and I'm trying to read up on them. From Microsoft's instructions, I tried running the code on two different COMs. On the port  which the printer is connected I have an exception if I try to open it (portname not found) but I'm sure the port name is COM1 . For the XON/XOFF, I would like to read the free buffer character (it is the only indication I have in the printer manual).

Comment: There are some PowerShell commands at the end of the following post that may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70614758/10024425